# Single word for "to fund the totality (of)"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is a one- or two-word phrase that means "to fund the totality of a program: staff, office space, supplies, and program funding" that is often used in grant applications?

Comment: [bear the cost, chip in, cover cost, finance, foot the bill, fund, pay for, pick up the bill, pick up the check, pick up the tab, settle;   accord, award, back, bequeath, bestow, come through with, confer, contribute, donate, empower, enable, endue, enhance, enrich, establish, favor, finance, found, fund, furnish, grant, heighten, invest, lay on, leave, make over, organize, promote, provide, settle on, sponsor, subscribe, subsidize, supply, support, underwrite, vest in, will](http://thesaurus.com/browse/fund?s=t).

Comment: "Fund the total project cost" seems to be quite widespread.

Comment: Perhaps [fill your boots](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fill-your-boots) is the expression you are looking for. Although officialdom is seldom so honest.

Comment: I think to *underwrite* more often means *to bear the costs of any funding **shortfall*** that may arise if other sources of funds prove inadequate.

Comment: Such questions (help me remember the word I forgot) are not constructive.

Answer (score 4):

In the grant writing I have done we often referred to direct and indirect services. "Direct" might be the assigned staff person and "indirect" a portion of the light bill. One possibility might be to say something like "the grant will fund all direct and indirect services provided."

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are seeking funding for "all [*operating expenses*](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Operating+Expense)" (as opposed to [capital expenditures](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/capital%20expenditure)).

Answer (score 1):

**Total costs** include dirct and indirect costs (which are described [here](http://www.ehow.com/list_7497692_indirect-costs-comes-grant-writing.html)).